# DTD validation in C#

Tags: c#, dtd

I have an XML file with the following DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" "localdtd.dtd"[]>
```

I am trying to validate the XML against localdtd.dtd which is residing on my root folder using following code

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

using (var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(
                          new StringReader(xmlcontent), 
                          new XmlReaderSettings() 
                          { 
                             ProhibitDtd = false, ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
                          }   ) )
{
            xml.Load(xmlreader); 
}
```

I am getting the following error

Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\localdtd.dtd'.

Can we specify the location of localdtd.dtd file?

Comment: where you load xml file in your code ?

Comment: I am loading it from a string like this new StringReader(xmlcontent), where xmlcontent has the content form database and it includes doctype at the top with dtd declaration.

Comment: this path is correct "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\localdtd.dtd" ??? at this path you have an xml ? if yes then what is its extension .xml or dtd

Comment: as i said xml is stroed in DB and with in that dtd is declared. I have the localdtd.dtd file in my root folder so i want to specify somehow to look for the .dtd from my root folder instead of going to default asp.net folder which is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> `<!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" "localdtd.dtd"[]>`

I believe you can specify the direct path using:

> `<!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" @"C:\MYLOCATION\localdtd.dtd"[]>`

Or try to add:

> XmlResolver.ResolveUri(@"C:\MYLOCATION\localdtd.dtd", null)

To your `XmlReaderSettings`.

Comment: I've used the `XmlReaderSettings` approach before

Comment: My `DOCTYPE`s are typically in the format of `<!DOCTYPE SomeDTD SYSTEM "SomeDTD.dtd">`. I'll admit I'm not familiar with the approach the OP is using. I prefer adjusting the settings and leaving the `DOCTYPE` as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes same error, i managed it working by changing the localdtd.dtd in <!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" "localdtd.dtd"[]> to http://localhost/localdtd.dtd <!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" "h t t p://localhost/localdtd.dtd"[]>. This is still a work around, I think there is way we can specify dtd location using xmlresolver in XmlReaderSettings...

Answer (score 0):

For relative path use **~**

```
<!DOCTYPE localdtd PUBLIC "-//local host//local dtd - XML//EN" "~/localdtd.dtd"[]>
```